# Obtener data- de un checkbox y al estar seleccionado mostrar valor del data- en un input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, data

Estoy haciendo una web de reserva de oficina(PHP, MySql), para reservar una hora muestra un tabla donde sale la hora de inicio, hora de termino, disponibilidad y precio, cada hora tiene un checkbox al final para poder seleccionarlo, todo bien hasta ahí, lo que necesito es que al hacer click muestre en unos input(text) los valores que tengo asignados con data (data-hora-inicio y data-hora-termino)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el click de Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(".checkbox").click(function(){
    var data_inicio = $(this).attr("data-hora-inicio");
    
    alert(data_inicio);
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Ejemplo checkbox</label>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" data-hora-inicio="8"/>
```